# How can I compress all of these function into one function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, show-hide

This code makes extra paragraphs appear when I click on a anchor tag but I do not want all of these function as it get messy I was wondering how I could compress this code into one single function I do not mind jquery but I would prefer javascript, but just do what is more efficient.

```
    function showmore1()
            {
                var more_1 = document.getElementById("learnmore_1");
                if (more_1.style.display == "block") 
                {
                    more_1.style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('showmore_1').innerHTML ='<a>Even More History</a>';
                }
                else 
                {
                    more_1.style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('showmore_1').innerHTML ='<a>Show Less</a>';
                }
                }
    function showmore2()
            {
                var more_2 = document.getElementById("learnmore_2");
                if (more_2.style.display == "block") 
                {
                    more_2.style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('showmore_2').innerHTML ='<a>Even More Why programming</a>';
                }
                else 
                {
                    more_2.style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('showmore_2').innerHTML ='<a>Show Less</a>';
                }
                }
    function showmore3()
            {
                var more_3 = document.getElementById("learnmore_3");
                if (more_3.style.display == "block") 
                {
                    more_3.style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('showmore_3').innerHTML ='<a>Even More Skills</a>';
                }
                else 
                {
                    more_3.style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('showmore_3').innerHTML ='<a>Show Less</a>';
                }
            }
    function showmore4()
            {
                var more_4 = document.getElementById("learnmore_4");
                if (more_4.style.display == "block") 
                {
                    more_4.style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('showmore_4').innerHTML ='<a>Even More Accomplishments</a>';
                }
                else 
                {
                    more_4.style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('showmore_4').innerHTML ='<a>Show Less</a>';
                }
            }
```

Comment: This question would be more appropiate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull out the bits of the code which change (variables) inside your function, then combine the functionality and pass the variables to the function to insert.

```
function showmore(id, more, less) {
    var more = document.getElementById('learnmore_'+id);

    if(more.style.display == "block") {
        more.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('showmore_'+id).innerHTML ='<a>'+more+'</a>';
    } else {
        more.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('showmore_'+id).innerHTML ='<a>'+less+'</a>';
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
showmore(1, 'Even more accomplishments', 'Show less');
```

Comment: One minor problem it gives me when switching it says undefined and [object HTMLDivElement] as the changed names

Answer (score 0):

maybe this work i dont test it

```
function showmore(number,moreMessage,lessMessage)
{
    var more = document.getElementById("learnmore_"+number);
    if (more.style.display == "block") 
    {
        more.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('showmore_'+number).innerHTML ='<a>'+moreMessage+'</a>';
    }
    else 
    {
        more.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('showmore_'+number).innerHTML ='<a>'+lessMessage+'</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't cater for different wording for the anchors like the other 2 answers

Answer (score 0):

```
 function showmore(id, moreMessage, lessMessage)
        {
            var more = document.getElementById('more'+id);
            if (more.style.display == "block") 
            {
                more.style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('showmore_'+id).innerHTML ='<a>'+moreMessage+'</a>';
            }
            else 
            {
                more.style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('showmore_'+id,).innerHTML ='<a>'+lessMessage+'</a>';
            }
        }
```